# Cannot see Fragments in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

Although I can scroll in the `ViewPager`, the physical fragments themselves are not visible for some reason.

FYI - I have an Activity with tabs using a ViewPager. Inside the **first** tab/fragment, I have the code below. So essentially, I have an App with a ViewPager controlling the tabs and there's another ViewPager inside one of the Tabs which is to control a bunch of images. I have tested the Fragment in question by putting it inside the top level view pager and it works perfectly fine! It's only when I put it inside the view pager in question does it not render anything...

So, this is the hierarchy for a better understanding:

```
MainActivity has a ...
  ViewPager (3 fragments showing the tab content) has a ...
    1st TabFragment has a ...
      ViewPager (3 fragments showing images) <--- I can't see these, but I can swipe on them for some reason.
```

Unfortunately... None of the Fragments are visible, HOWEVER... I can still swipe for some reason to the last fragment...Just nothing is visibly shown...

Layout with the ViewPager inside:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Code with ViewPager

```
final List<Fragment> imageFragments = new ArrayList<>();

for (final UserImage userImage : user.getImages()) {
    final SizeImage processed = userImage.getProcessed();
    imageFragments.add(UserImageFragment.newInstance(processed.getFullsize()));
}

final ImagesPagerAdapter imagesAdapter = new ImagesPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), imageFragments);
viewPager.setAdapter(imagesAdapter);
```

The PagerAdapter:

```
public class ImagesPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

@NonNull
private List<Fragment> fragments;

public ImagesPagerAdapter(@NonNull final FragmentManager fragmentManager,
                          @NonNull final List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fragmentManager);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(final int position) {
    return fragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragments.size();
    }
}
```

The Fragment:

```
public class UserImageFragment extends Fragment {

@BindView(R.id.image_view)
ImageView imageView;

public static UserImageFragment newInstance(final String url) {
    final UserImageFragment fragment = new UserImageFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("url", url);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_image, container, false);

    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    final Bundle arguments = getArguments();

    if (arguments != null) {
        final String url = arguments.getString("url", null);
        if (url != null) {
            final Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);

            Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(url).into(imageView, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
          }
        }
      return view;
     }
   }
```

And here is xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/md_red_900">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@color/md_yellow_500" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is the code of your fragment class ? Can you display them alone in an activity ?

Comment: The code to the fragment is there already ^ `UserImageFragment`.

Comment: Are your success or fail Toast messages displaying? What does the layout with the ViewPager look like?

Comment: It's always a Success showing. I've added the ViewPager layout to the question

Comment: Seems like image returning from URL is transparent

Comment: It's not - I pasted the image in the URL and it shows an actual image. Besides, the fragment layout has a layout background of red and the image view itself is yellow...So something SHOULD show but nothing is showing at all... Just clear white... Nothing showing at all.

Answer (score 3):

To show Fragments inside another Fragment, use **getChildFragmentManager()** instead of **getFragmentManager()**

```
final ImagesPagerAdapter imagesAdapter = new 
 ImagesPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), imageFragments);
   viewPager.setAdapter(imagesAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be obvious at first sight but **don't try to cache or prepare fragments for a fragment adapter**. `Fragment(State)PagerAdapter.getItem` has to return a new item and when the method is called is managed internally by the adapter.

Let the fragment adapter have data it needs to construct fragments at the right time:

```
final List<UserImage> userImages = user.getImages();
final ImagesPagerAdapter imagesAdapter = new ImagesPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), userImages);
viewPager.setAdapter(imagesAdapter);
```

And implement the fragment adapter so that `getItem` returns a new fragment:

```
public class ImagesPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    @NonNull
    private List<UserImage> userImages;

    public ImagesPagerAdapter(@NonNull final FragmentManager fragmentManager,
                              @NonNull final List<UserImage> userImages) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.userImages = userImages;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(final int position) {
        final UserImage userImage = userImages.get(position);
        final SizeImage processed = userImage.getProcessed();
        return UserImageFragment.newInstance(processed.getFullsize())
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return userImages.size();
    }
}
```

Here I see two options for improvement:

1. Replace `List<UserImage>` with `List<SizeImage>` or `List<whatever getFullSize returns>`. The less implementation details you leak to the adapter the better.
2. If `userImage.getProcessed().getFullsize()` takes time (accesses disk, performs computation) do that asynchronously in one of `UserImageFragment` lifecycle methods - defer to when it's needed and don't block UI thread.

Neither `FragmentPagerAdapter` nor `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` are built with updates in mind so

1. Don't try to modify the `userImages` list.
2. If the images change replace and reattach the whole adapter.